# How to retrieve the block author of a specific block using Polkadot JS API?

Tags: block, polkadot-js

In their [docs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/cookbook/blocks), they showed how to get the author of the newest blocks, but I want to get the author of a specific block. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a `blockHash` to `api.derive.chain.getHeader()`, like:

```
// retrieve the last header (hash optional) <---- Here
const blockHash = '0x36d9aabf232d29eae55ccc299c7a5b13522244bffe2ee7220f830041629586e0'
const header = await api.derive.chain.getHeader(blockHash);
console.log(`#${header.number}: ${header.author}`);
```